# How to make winforms tablelayout add new rows of the same size?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a table Layout with 2 rows and two columns, each row and column are set to take 50% of the screen, dividing the screen up into four quadrants. I then dynamically add controls to the tablelaout at run time and set the dock property of these controls to fill, like this:
[image]

but when I add more then four controls the new controls shrink like this:
[image]

how can I fix this and make them all the same size?

Comment: When you add the new row, make sure the rowstyle is also set to percent and that the number used is the same one as that of the previous rows.  Perhaps you could show your code that creates the new row?

Comment: I'm not actively adding new rows, I'm just adding my controls to the tablelayout and I've set it's GrowStyle to addrows

Comment: You need to be explicitly adding Rows so you can control the RowStyle of the newly added row.  First increase the RowCount property by one, then add a new RowStyle to the RowStyles property.  Then when you add those controls they'll use the config of the new row you just added.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want them to all take up equal space vertically, and the original rows were set to Percent with the same value...here's a quick example of how to add two more controls to a new row:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RowStyle rs = new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].Height);
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(rs);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    btn.Text = "x";
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);

    btn = new Button();
    btn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    btn.Text = "x";
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```